# Integrating Pylint in pycharm

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pylint

I am trying to integrate Pylint in my pycharm using ubuntu.I did the following steps:

1. which pylint (on ubuntu)
2. I got the path and copied it
3. I went to tools - settings -- external tools -- added pylint using plus -- added arguments and working directory -- apply
4. But it is showing the following error

   > Error running 'Pylint': Cannot run program "\home\prachi.local\bin\pylint" (in directory "C:\Users\sanya"): CreateProcess error=2, T
5. I tried changing the configuration in my working directory but still getting the same error

Is there any way out to overcome this problem?